# PHP with multi server

Tags: php, multiserver

I would like to make a page for uploading some of my local records to the web server.

The `Table Structure` from local and web server are the same.

My question is, how to connect to both server?

```
<?php
$localCon = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$localCon) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("[table]", $localCon);

$serverCon = mysql_connect("mysql", "[username]", "[password]");
if (!$serverCon) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("[table]", $serverCon);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM [table]");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['[coloumn]'];
    echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($localCon);
mysql_close($serverCon);
?>
```

I got error for both local and web server.

Or is there another way for me to upload the local records to the web?

```
This is the error msg:
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in [addres]
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (trying to connect via tcp://mysql:3306) in [addres]
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in [address]
Could not connect:
```

Comment: What error do you have? anyway in your code you are only fetching information from the remote server I think.

Comment: I have edited my question, this is the message I received when error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear: Unless you have an entry for `mysql` in your `hosts` file, `mysql` is not a valid network address.

You need to specify the address of the remote server as the first parameter in your `mysql_connect` call.

Please note that the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and it is recommended to switch to PDO or mysqli with prepared statements.

Comment: Yeah, but is there any possibilities to `upload` my local data to the web server?, AFAIK, connecting web server need to put my `PHP` file in the server, but if I put in the server, I cannot connect my local `database`

Comment: @Sieryuu Don't know about the `mysql_*` extension, but I don't see any reason why I could not connect to multiple databases / servers in PDO.

Comment: Can PDO connect local and server at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to more databases but you need the handle in your query.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM [table]", $serverCon);
```

Otherwise you don't know from where you make the query and its not working.

Comment: But anyway AFAIK, connecting local server is when we put the file in the local, and connecting web server is when we put the file on the web, can we connect both, if I just wan to put it in the local place?

Comment: Yes but you should look at the performance. A connection to a remote host has no good performance. So if you need only a replication you could use a Master/Slace replication.